# Cloud9 VFS connection does not exist error [Node JS]

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloud9

I was trying out the Cloud9 IDE from AWS by creating a "Hello World" application in Node JS. I used the guide from the following [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloud9/latest/user-guide/app-preview.html#app-preview-run-app) but when I went to "Preview" my application the browser showed a page that said the "VFS connection does not exist". I am pretty new to server management and I don't know what VFS stands for, so I don't know where to start looking for a solution. All of my searches led to forums of people talking about ruby on rails, and the error was specific to that framework. Anyone experiencing the same problem, and are there any solutions?

```
let express = require("express");
let app = express();

app.get("/", (req,res) => {
    console.log("Hello");
});

app.listen(8080,"127.0.0.1",() => {
    console.log("Server Running ...");
});
```

P.S. I know I am not sending a page back in this code, I just want the console to output the "Hello" statement so that I know that the server is receiving the requests.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Internet Explorer. I also faced this issue in Google Chrome. I don't know why this happens, but Internet Explorer is the solution.

Comment: Hey there and welcome to StackOverflow! I'm passing by just to let you know that this kind of answer would be better suited as a comment in the original question, since it's more of a vague and possible solution. Still, thanks for helping the author and keep up with the participation in our community! :) See ya!